# jqueryui draggable, can't drag outside of the container

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to move a draggable element outside of the container, [as you can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78XNX/3/).

I'm using the default draggable code:

```
$("#drag ul li").draggable();
```

The element can't be dragged outside of the result block.
I've tried the containment option, but it's still not working

Comment: There are no problems with dragging the elements anywhere inside the iframe. But of course you can't drag an element out of an iframe (result area of jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78XNX/4/

```
ul {background-color: #FF0000;}
```

It is possible to drag elements outside of its container. The results block is part of the fiddle page itself and somehow works with internal frames (or better iframes), which has nothing todo with with your website i guess. If your question is, if its possible to drag it outside the fiddle resultbox, i have to say: no.